# How can I aggregate cloudwatch logs for Lambda-edge automatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda-edge

For a Lambda Edge a CloudWatch Log Group is created in a region where endpoint was requested.
I'd like to gather all the logs, including these which will appear in the regions, which are not activated yet.

I know how to do it manually (go to each used region, add subscription filters, etc), but how can I do it automatically, does anybody know the answer?